# SQL Server stuck in single_user with auto_update_statistics_async on

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, single-user

[Books online states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx)

> Before you set the database to SINGLE_USER, verify the
>   AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC option is set to OFF. When set to ON, the
>   background thread used to update statistics takes a connection against
>   the database, and you will be unable to access the database in
>   single-user mode.

I got to know this only after the fact. What do I do now, when shutting down the entire instance is not an option as there are critical DB's on it as well?

I don't have the permission to kill the 'sa' login TASK MANAGER processes that the statistics update seems to use, and even having tried a brute-force trick where I'd just try to get into the DB some 3000 times in a row for a few times, doesn't help.

Even though I have the VIEW SERVER STATE permissions I can see no stats jobs by querying sys.dm_exec_background_job_queue so [`KILL STATS JOB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180016.aspx) doesn't appear to help.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.